# <p> introduced on new line in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, radeditor

Using CustomRadEditorCtrl, when hitting a new line on Firefox or Chrome, it introduces a `<br/>` tag, which is fine for us. 
However in IE the editor wraps up the line inside `<p>...</p>` tags, thus introducing a double spacing. Is there any way to put IE in line with the other browsers?
We have tried `edit.NewLineMode = EditorNewLineModes.Br` to no avail

Comment: Are you using the latest version and if not, does it help? If you are not using the vanilla control, does removing your custom code help?

Comment: I'm not using the latest version, I'm using version 2013.1.417.35 I'm using the vanilla control, not sure what to do next

Comment: Upgrade to the latest. At least try the online demo first: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx. If it does not exhibit the issue, then either it is a bug that has been fixed, or you are using an IE version newer than the Telerik version you use and it is a compatibility issue resolved in a later version.
Also, try setting NewLineMode=P to always use paragraphs to get consistency.

Comment: The demo exhibits the same behaviour in IE, I'm wondering how that can be overriden

Comment: Did you try newlinemode=p? Browsers have some differences ehen  it comes to handling rich text editing

Comment: for some reason it ignores the `.NewLineMode` command

Comment: The demo does? Never seen that before. Delete all the content in case your cursor had been in a weird element and try again

Comment: Sorry I forgot to set the NewLineBreak, seems to be working fine, I'll upgrade to a most recet version of the control